Ace editor cursor jumps unexpectedly after typing three spaces
I'm encountering an issue with Ace Editor in my project. After typing three spaces, the cursor behaves erratically. It jumps or doesn't respond as expected. I've tried adjusting the font family to Monaco and other solutions suggested online, but none have resolved the issue.
Has anyone else experienced this problem with Ace Editor, and how can I fix it?


Are there any errors displayed in the browser console? Looks like there is an error in onChange listener

No, there is nothing in the browser console.
